# Deleting element from a list

Tags: python

I'm working on project, where I have to find largest non-decreasing subarray of prime. The problem is the non-decreasing part. I have no idea how to compare 2 elements of the list and depending on results delete last element. Here is the code:

```
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
prvocisla = []

for i in nums:
    kontrola = True
    for j in range(2,abs(i)):
        if abs(i)%j ==0:
            kontrola = False
    if kontrola == True:
        prvocisla.append(i)
    else:
        prvocisla.append(0)

prvni = int()
druhe = int()
listprvocisel = list()
nejdelsirada = list()

for i in prvocisla:
    prvni = i
    druhe = prvni
    if  prvni != 0 and prvni != -1 and prvni !=1 and ( druhe == 0 or druhe == -1 or druhe ==1):
        listprvocisel.append(prvni)
    elif prvni >= druhe and prvni != 0 and prvni != -1 and prvni !=1 and druhe != 0 and druhe !=-1 and druhe !=1:
        listprvocisel.append(prvni)
        for i in range(0, len(listprvocisel)+1):
            if i>i+1:
                listprvocisel.pop(i+1)
    else:
        if len(listprvocisel) > len(nejdelsirada):
            nejdelsirada = listprvocisel
            listprvocisel = []
        elif len(listprvocisel) == len(nejdelsirada):
            soucetprvnirady = 0
            for i in listprvocisel:
                soucetprvnirady += i
            soucetdruherady = 0
            for i in nejdelsirada:
                soucetdruherady += i
            if soucetprvnirady > soucetdruherady:
                nejdelsirada = listprvocisel
                listprvocisel = []
        elif prvni != 0 and prvni != -1 and prvni !=1 and druhe != 0 and druhe !=-1 and druhe !=1:
            listprvocisel.append(prvni)


delkanejdelsirady = len(nejdelsirada)
soucetnejdelsirady = 0
for i in nejdelsirada:
    soucetnejdelsirady += i


print(delkanejdelsirady)
print(soucetnejdelsirady)
```

P.S. I'm new to programming, sorry about that spagetoid of a code.

Comment: You should start by writing a function to determine whether or not a number is prime.  Reading this code I get the sense that you've skipped a few chapters ahead in whatever course you're taking -- it's not even syntactically valid Python, and what you're describing is a problem that would be more suitable for someone who's at least already learned the basics.  Is there earlier material that you could go back and review?

Comment: I patched the syntax errors, which were probably just cut-and-paste issues.

Comment: What do you need help with?  Do you know how to compare two list elements?  Do you know how to delete one element from a list?  There are standard Python library functions to do this sort of thing.  If you're not asking about that, then I think you need to clarify your question so that others can understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove an item with index using:

```
l = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Bob', 'Dave']
print(l)
# ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Bob', 'Dave']

l.remove('Alice')
print(l)
# ['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Bob', 'Dave']
```

Or an item using the place in list starting from 0

```
l = list(range(10))
print(l)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

del l[0]
print(l)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

del l[-1]
print(l)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

del l[6]
print(l)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```